# Listview not scrolling totally android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a ListView that is not scrolling for complete. I inserted 20 items, but the listview is scrolling until the item 15º.

My Layout XML code here :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:background="@color/sky" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvQuote"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:text="@string/QuoteTeste"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14pt" />

        <Space
            android:id="@+id/espaco"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp" >
        </Space>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAutor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvQuote"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvQuote"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:text="(Carlos Drummond)"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/checklistview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here a screenshot:
[image: My view]

I don't understand WHY this is happening. For example, If I put 6 items, the 6º item is not show and I can't scroll the listview.  Missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your layout xml

change it with this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topPart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/sky" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvQuote"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:text="@string/QuoteTeste"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14pt" />

        <Space
            android:id="@+id/espaco"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp" >
        </Space>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAutor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvQuote"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvQuote"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:text="(Carlos Drummond)"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/checklistview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topPart" >
    </ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this but my listview disappear, the first RelativeLayout (blue with the textview) fills all the screen. Here a screenshot [link](http://hhide.me/KxB)

Comment: I changed the second relativelayout height. you might also want to add some margins

Comment: Works! I made that changes and put layout_height with static height, like this ' android:layout_height="200dp" '. Here is the complete XML file [link](http://pastebin.com/J98X1TTw)

Comment: Otherwise, I don't understand why was not working and now is working. What the explanation of your solution?

Comment: In your layout your second relativelayout was under the 1st one (because of the linearlayout) but you told the second relativelayout to fill_parent meaning taking as much space as the parent is taking (which is the whole screen but since that layout starts after the 1st relativelayout it has to continue out of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You should not add multiple enties below each other using android:layout_height="fill_parent" or "match_parent" (which is the same) in the same layout as you do in the LinearLayout.

Make it another RelativeLayout with using layout_below, layout_parentOnBottom and other options or place everything into one huge relative layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/toppart"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/sky" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvQuote"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:text="@string/QuoteTeste"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14pt" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/espaco"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp" >
    </Space>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAutor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvQuote"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvQuote"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="(Carlos Drummond)"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottompart"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toppart"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/checklistview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes you can but then you get the result he is having ;)

Comment: Replaced "can" by "should" ;-)

Comment: Sorry, can you seed some code about what you are talking?

Comment: Added code, but needs improvements to match your layout needs.